# Focus the first field in modal forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, marionette

I am using Bootstrap, from Twitter for genereting modal-dialog in a Marionette Application.

I would like to know what is the best way to focus the first field in modal forms without using fancy javascript.

Here my code:

```
var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
    modal: '#modal'
});

app.vent.on('showModal', function (view) {
    var modal = app.modal;

    modal.show(view);
    modal.$el.modal({
        show: true,
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap modal input field focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474862/twitter-bootstrap-modal-input-field-focus)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the *shown* event as seen in the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

```
modal.$el.on('shown', function () {
  $('input:text:visible:first', this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If `odupont`'s answer didn't help you,(like me,) try this:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#firstField').focus();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('input:first', this).focus();
});
```