# Twitter bootstrap modal input field focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following modal form from example:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Enter something: <input type="text" id="myInput">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my input field to be focused after modal is shown.
I've tryed both autofocus and setting field focus on `$('modal').shown()` event. It kinda focuses field (I have another event which shows label when field is focused) but in fact field is not focused and I have to press `TAB` to focus it again. 
I also tried something like this:

```
$(".modal").on('shown', function() {
    $(this).find("[autofocus]:first").focus();
});
```

and setting `autofocus:"autofocus"` attribute for my field.
It gave same effect.
Everything I tried works for when modal is just a usual div, it gets focus on page load. But when modal is triggered by button - nothing works (sure I change logic also, when modal is just a usual div I can focus it onload, when I trigger by button I take it into account and try to solve it accordingly).

What I want is just field to be focused after modal is loaded, so that it has blinking cursor and user can just start typing.

Only thing that worked is changing bootstrap.js itself, I've put `$("#myInput").focus()` somewhere inside bootstrap.js modal section but well I forgot where it was, and second - I think it's not good to change bootstrap.js API, there must be easier and more elegant solution. Advice me please, thanks xD

**UPDATE:**
First of all, thanks for your help!
Thanks to you I figured out that problem I had is Rails problem.

Here is what I did:
1). `rails generate controller home index`
2). *app/views/home/index.html* and *app/assets/javascript/something.js* are like in this jsFiddle provided by **robertklep**: http://jsfiddle.net/JCaFp/
4). *jquery-1.9.1.js* and *bootstrap.js* are in *app/assets/javascript/* (both are fresh from website, nothing changed)
5). *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb* - I guess this file is the key of our solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Udc</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Still doesn't work. All js files get included, but when I open my modal in browser - input get focus for a moment and gets unfocused again.

I've also tried this:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "somehow" %>
```

Still same stuff.
Suggestions? :)

**UPDATE:**

**Solved it!**

After changing my `somehow.js` to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal").on('shown', function() {
        $(this).find("[autofocus]:first").focus();
    });
});
```

and `application.html.erb` stylesheet to:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "somehow" %>
```

it works as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Your code inside the `shown` handler works just fine for me (provided you actually set the `autofocus` attribute, otherwise the selector won't find it): [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/JCaFp/)

Comment: robert, can you please add your comment as an answer? I will mark it as the right one :)

Answer (score 82):

I think the [shown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) event name changed in Bootstrap 3, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634933/41621) post.

> As [@MrDBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488293/mrdba) notes, in
>   Bootstrap 3 the event name is
>   [changed](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) to
>   `shown.bs.modal`.

So, for Bootstrap 3 use:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').focus();
})
```

Comment: This really is the definitive answer, because even if you set the field to autofocus in the HTML control then the control will get focus for a brief moment as the modal dialog appears and then lose focus again. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

For a general solution that doesn't require specific code for each dialog, you can use this:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).find('input:text:visible:first').focus();
})
```

Comment: I still wonder why bootstrap is specifically overriding the focus, and how that can be controlled.

Comment: Had to drop the :text for may case (password field), but otherwise works nicely.

Comment: You can remove the following line (it's redundant in this example): `lastfocus = $(this);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. 
I changed $('.modal').on to $(document).on for my use case - a single page app with dynamically generated modals.

Comment: For an even more general solution, the `text` inside the selector could be removed, so that *any* kind of input will be detected.

Comment: @pschwamb  how did you manage to keep the focus in the modal when you reach the last element in your modal? because with solution it works as long as you don't reach the last element and when you do, the focus is back to the background.

Answer (score 13):

Try removing `tabindex="-1"` and it works nice.

So change this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

To this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalID" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: This whole ordeal with auto focusing an element has been driving me nuts until I came across this answer. Removing the tabindex="-1" from my dialog fixed the issue for me!

Comment: Oh my, this solves the problem too. Deserves more upvotes! But, there probably is a reason why tabindex is -1. Wonder if we break something by removing this.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis Removing tabindex breaks the functionality to close the modal with the Esc key.

Answer (score 8):

If you have problems with "shown.bs.modal", just set a timeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('#myInput').focus();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just changing `$(this).find("[autofocus]:first").focus();` to `$(this).find("#myInput").focus();` made it work for me. If you have changed the Bootstrap API and want to undo that change, you can always just re-download and replace the file.

Answer (score 6):

I removed tabindex="-1" and it works so nice.

My HTML code before changes:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

My HTML code after changes:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

My Input code:

```
<input id="tblModalNombreConductor" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Ej: Armando Casas" autofocus/>
```

And I have no configurations in my Javascript code.

Comment: This works only once for me. Closing and re-opening the modal doesn't focus.

Answer (score 3):

I think the updated answer is pretty clever. Here is another way to solve it.

Bootstrap 3.2's js file includes a script to manage focus during and after the modal's fade transition. This interferes with any jQuery, javascript or rails+HTML5 focusing on a form field in the modal - bootstrap removes your focus after the modal loads.

To remove bootstrap's ability to override your focus, comment out this line in the Modal script area:

```
transition ?
    that.$element.find('.modal-dialog') // wait for modal to slide in
      .one($.support.transition.end, function () {
        // that.$element.focus().trigger(e)
        // the line above is stealing your focus after modal loads!
      })
      .emulateTransitionEnd(300) :
    that.$element.focus().trigger(e)
```

Now your field should be able to have focus in any modal form.

Comment: I am seeing this also. I'm wondering what that line is attempting to accomplish. Looks as if it's trying to set focus on the modal.  Is there a way to take advantage of what bootstrap is doing here rather than monkey-patching the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:
e.g

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter first name", autofocus: true%>
```

just add this: autofocus: true

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$('#the-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#the-input').focus();
});
```