# How to remove the focusin event listener from modal in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I have a legacy app with a modal that is unfortunately using a kendo dropdown list element (bound to an ajax call and with filtering etc - i dont want to rewrite this if i dont have too). So when the modal opens, and you focus on the dropdown list, the modal assumes you are clicking outside it, and takes the focus off the dropdown list - cuasing it to close as soon as you open it... I had fixed it in Boostrap 4 with this code:

```
    $("#theModalId").on('shown.bs.modal',function () {
            $(document).off('focusin');
    })
```

However that is no longer working in bootstrap 5. I think possibly because the focusin event might no longer be on the document element itself? I can see bootstrap is adding a focusin event - but i dont know which element it is adding it too as the above code no longer works. I also tried removing it from the theModal element but that didnt work either.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is adding a `ev.preventDefault()` in the kendo stuff an option?

Comment: Hi @ITgoldman - thank you - i did try preventDefault and stopPropagation in a few scenarios and it was preventing the DDL from working correctly, But thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found if you remove the filter option from the dropdown it fixes this issue, but then you might as well just use a regular select.

Or you can keep the filter and fix the issue by apply the following suggestion provided by some Levi dude in this thread: https://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-closes-when-setting-filter-option (Thanks Levi)
Nothing else seemed to work for me! Here is Levi's implementation:

```
// Popup extension.
// Sets up kendo popups (used in all sorts of widgets) to check if the widget
// is being included in a bootstrap modal. If so, the popup should append to
// the modal instead of the page body.
//
// For the most part, popups work fine without this. However, DropdownList with
// a filter option does not. This is because the filter attempts to focus on
// filter input, which is outside the modal By default, Bootstrap modal will
// block this. It has an option to allow, but then it must be remembered to add
// everywhere.
//
// This allows filtered dropdownlists to 'just work'.
//
// http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-closes-when-setting-filter-option
//
// See for alternate solutions:
// http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-with-server-filtering-on-bootstrap-modal
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/28471072/246561
//
(function ($, kendo) {
 
    var
        _init = kendo.ui.Popup.fn.init;
 
    var Popup = kendo.ui.Popup.extend({
        init: function (element, options) {           
            // Only set appendTo if nothing was manually set in the options.
            if (options.appendTo === undefined) {
                // Find the nearest parent bootstrap modal, if any.
                var parentModal = $(options.anchor).closest('.modal');
 
                // Found one!
                if (parentModal.length > 0) {
                    options.appendTo = parentModal[0];
                }
            }
 
            // Call the base constructor.
            _init.call(this, element, options);
        }
    });
 
    kendo.ui.plugin(Popup);
}(window.kendo.jQuery, window.kendo));
```